# Primefaces schedule events not showing

Tags: jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

Project uses Spring Webflow and JSF (PrimeFaces). I have a schedule component. I use the sample code in the showcase. The schedule component is displayed on the page but the events are not displayed. Front-end code:

```
    <p:schedule value="${scheduleController.eventModel}" widgetVar="myschedule" > 
       <!-- listeners -->
    </p:schedule>

    <h:outputText value="DEBUG: ${scheduleController.eventModel.getEventCount()}" />
```

Back-end code is exactly the same with the sample code. I can get the debug message displaying the correct event number in the eventModel. But the events are not showing in the schedule. Anybody knows what happened here? Thank you very much.

Comment: try with `#` instead of `$` , value="#{scheduleController.eventModel}"

Comment: Hi thank you. I changed to "#" and it's not working. And I use <ui:composition> <ui:define> on the xhtml page. I am not sure whether this is related to the issue.

Comment: dunno . take a look at this place to see if you doing templating right http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example/