# How to use p:schedule correctly?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to create an agenda with jsf. I looked on [prime faces' website](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule/basic.xhtml?jfwid=1dff6) but I didn't catch how it works, even when I copied the code available on the website. I also made some research here and on google but I found nothing working for me.

So I tried to make the most simple exemple :

In my .xhtml :

```
<p:schedule value="#{agendaControl.planning}">
        
</p:schedule>
```

In my .java file :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@Stateful(passivationCapable=true)
public class AgendaControl {
    private ScheduleModel planning;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("test");
        planning = new DefaultScheduleModel();
    
        DefaultScheduleEvent<?> event = DefaultScheduleEvent.builder()
            .title("test")
            .startDate(LocalDateTime.now())
            .build();
    
        planning.addEvent(event);
    }

    public ScheduleModel getPlanning() {
        return planning;
    }

    public void setPlanning(ScheduleModel planning) {
        this.planning = planning;
    }
}
```

I would like to know what am I doing wrong and how should I use p:schedule to make it work fine ?

Thank you in advance for your help and any tips. I might have some beginner errors in my code, as I never used jsf before.

EDIT :

I looked on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973639/primefaces-schedule-events-not-showing), to see if my @PostConstruct annotated method worked, and yes it is. I have my "test" event in my planning variable.

Comment: Your question is not JavaSE related

Comment: the PrimeFaces Showcase has all the code you need.  So it tells me you are missing something if you followed the showcase example and it doesn't work

Comment: @Melloware, unfortunately yes, that was the reason. The problem is, in my opinion, there is too much code on primefaces for people who just want the most simple agenda. I am making a sample code with the minimum required and post it as an answer of my post. This could be helpful for someone. Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few more researches, I found out how to make it work as I wanted. Here is a sample minimalist code to make your agenda work.

NOTE : the referenced link in the question is about PrimeFaces 11. [Here is the link for PrimeFaces 8](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/data/schedule/basic.xhtml), version used here. The documentation is a bit clearer than the v11, don't forget to also check it out for other information !

agenda.xhtml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Agenda</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<body>
    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true"/>
    
    <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{agendaControl.eventModel}"></p:schedule>
</body>
```

AgendaControl.java :

```
@Named
@ViewScoped // import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
public class AgendaControl implements Serializable {
    private ScheduleModel eventModel;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        eventModel = new DefaultScheduleModel();

        DefaultScheduleEvent<?> event = DefaultScheduleEvent.builder()
            .title("Champions League Match")
            // as I tested, you NEED a start date and enddate
            .startDate(LocalDateTime.now())
            .endDate(LocalDateTime.of(2022, 1, 18, 12, 0)) // change with tomorrow's date
            .build();
        eventModel.addEvent(event);
    }

    public ScheduleModel getEventModel() {
        return eventModel;
    }
}
```

DO NOT FORGET : you need to add this depedency in your pom.xml (maven project in my case) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>8.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You won't be able to import the needed classes in your .java file if you forget it.

I hope this will helped you.

Comment: Please note that you were referencing the PrimeFaces 11 showcase in your question!

Comment: I added the link for the v8 in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Those links point to the showcase, not to the documentation. Documentation can be found at https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/schedule and https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/components/schedule